# MySQL - Update rows on criteria of values of the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a small data table

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test_Tb |  |  |  |
| test_T | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| test_C | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| test_Mb |  |  |  |
| test_M | 7 | 8 | 9 |

I would like to update the columns c2, c3 and c4 for rows where the values of c1 have value c1 = replace (c1, 'b', '')

**in a single request**, but I'm not even sure if it's possible anymore

to have finally
update test_Tb with values of row test_T, and test_Mb with values of row test_M

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test_Tb | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| test_T | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| test_C | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| test_Mb | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| test_M | 7 | 8 | 9 |

either my requests don't work, or it's too slow to complete ...
i'm lost.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
  c1 VARCHAR(255),
  c2 INT,
  c3 INT,
  c4 INT
);

INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_Tb', NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_T', 1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_C', 4, 5, 6);
INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_Mb', NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_M', 7, 8, 9);

    UPDATE Data AS target
INNER JOIN Data AS source ON target.c1 = CONCAT(source.c1, 'b')
       SET target.c2 = source.c2,
           target.c3 = source.c3,
           target.c4 = source.c4
     WHERE target.c1 NOT LIKE '%b'
```

Edit: Changed WHERE clause to "target.c1 NOT LIKE '%b'". With thanks to Barmar.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09248b/1)

Comment: You don't need to duplicate the condition `target.c1 = CONCAT(source.c1, 'b')` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I think you meant that to be `WHERE target.c1 NOT LIKE '%b'`

Comment: Just edited it to reflect that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
  c1 VARCHAR(255),
  c2 INT,
  c3 INT,
  c4 INT
);

INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_Tb', NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_T', 1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_C', 4, 5, 6);
INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_Mb', NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO Data VALUES ('test_M', 7, 8, 9);

UPDATE Data AS target,
       ( SELECT * FROM Data WHERE c1 NOT LIKE '%b') AS source
   SET target.c2 = source.c2,
       target.c3 = source.c3,
       target.c4 = source.c4
 WHERE target.c1 = CONCAT(source.c1, 'b')
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d958b/1/0)

Comment: We try to promote use of ANSI JOIN when answering.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions MySQL, so I do not understand your comment.

Comment: I don't understand your response. ANSI JOIN is the preferred syntax in MySQL.

Comment: Your solution is correct, we just prefer to teach people modern SQL syntax.

Comment: `JOIN` is much more readable when you're joining several tables, since the `ON` conditions are connected to the specific tables, rather than being mixed in with all the other `WHERE` conditions. And if you mix `INNER` and `OUTER` join, it's necessary for correctness.

Comment: There is an INNER JOIN in my DML, but also an OUTER JOIN?

Comment: No, I was speaking in general. We're trying to teach good coding practice here, aren't we?

Comment: Added a second answer with an explicit JOIN. Note that that solution will be slower.